# Magento2 rewrite: product resource collection class does not effect on functions

Tags: magento2, overrides, class, magento2.1.5

I have rewrite catalog product resource collection [**`Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection`**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php#L33).

Class  **override successfully but functions override  is not working**.

Suppose, i want overrider [**setOrder()**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php#L2309)function. But it does not works . ***Always calling Core function instead of rewrite class function***

### Class

```
<?php
namespace AmitBera\CoreRewrite\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\ResourceModel\Product;

class Collection extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
{

    protected $appState;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory $eavEntityFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory $universalFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\State $catalogProductFlatState,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory $productOptionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Url $catalogUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
                $entityFactory,
                $logger,
                $fetchStrategy,
                $eventManager,
                $eavConfig,
                $resource,
                $eavEntityFactory,
                $resourceHelper,
                $universalFactory,
                $storeManager,
                $moduleManager,
                $catalogProductFlatState,
                $scopeConfig,
                $productOptionFactory,
                $catalogUrl,
                $localeDate,
                $customerSession,
                $dateTime,
                $groupManagement,
                        $connection
            );
        $this->_appState = $appState;

    }
   public function setOrder($attribute, $dir = \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_DESC)
    {
        echo __METHOD__;
        exit;
        if ($attribute == 'price') {
            $this->addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
        } else {
            parent::setOrder($attribute, $dir);
        }
        return $this;
    }


}
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNameSpaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="AmitBera_CoreRewrite" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/> 
            <module name="Magento_CatalogSearch"/>         
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Vault"/>
            <module name="Magento_OfflineShipping"/>           
        </sequence>     
    </module>
</config>
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" 
        type="AmitBera\CoreRewrite\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" />
</config>
```

Whenever use

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
echo get_class($productCollection );
```

**result:**

> AmitBera\CoreRewrite\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor

### Question:

- i donot understand why   i am not able to override function
  setorder()
- Why `echo get_class($productCollection );` give   Interceptor class

> AmitBera\CoreRewrite\Model\Rewrite\Catalog\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor

Comment: I am facing the same issue when I try to override addPriceData() method

Comment: I am facing same issue when i try to override `function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC)` and `function _productLimitationPrice($joinLeft = false)` method.

Please give this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you overwriting 
`Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection`, just traverse this folder location, you will find the file and folder with same name i.e Collection. So its points to folder location collection.

If you want to do some function with sorting overwrite `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\ProductLimitation` or using plugin concept to set `$productLimitationFilters`